# Python - json without whitespaces

Tags: python, json, serialization

I just realized that `json.dumps()` adds spaces in the JSON object

e.g.

```
{'duration': '02:55', 'name': 'flower', 'chg': 0}
```

how can remove the spaces in order to make the JSON more compact and save bytes to be sent via HTTP?

such as:

```
{'duration':'02:55','name':'flower','chg':0}
```

Comment: Python 3.4 fixes this: `Changed in version 3.4: Use (',', ': ') as default if indent is not None.` https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump

Comment: If saving bytes on the wire is the goal, gzip'ing large JSON request bodies and setting the content-encoding header accordingly will usually make a much bigger difference vs. simply stripping whitespace.

Answer (score 445, accepted):

```
json.dumps(separators=(',', ':'))
```

Comment: Very useful for doctests with json validation.

Comment: And also note that `indent=0` generates newlines, while `indent=None` (default) does not in 2.7. All is clearly stated at: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump

Comment: `ujson` defaults to dumps without whitespace but sadly it doesn't support `separators` keyword so can't add space back if desired. It is a lot faster though vs built in `json`!

Comment: I arrived here trying to compare the Django `request.body` to the `request.data` so folks might find this useful `bytes(json.dumps(request.data, separators=(',', ':')), 'utf-8') == request.body`

Answer (score 77):

In some cases you may want to get rid of the **trailing whitespaces** only.
You can then use

```
json.dumps(separators=(',', ': '))
```

There is a space after `:` but not after `,`.

This is useful for diff'ing your JSON files (in version control such as `git diff`), where some editors will get rid of the trailing whitespace but python json.dump will add it back.

*Note: This does not exactly answers the question on top, but I came here looking for this answer specifically. I don't think that it deserves its own QA, so I'm adding it here.*

Answer (score 24):

*Compact encoding:*

```
import json

list_1 = [1, 2, 3, {'4': 5, '6': 7}]

json.dumps(list_1, separators=(',', ':'))

print(list_1)
```

```
[1,2,3,{"4":5,"6":7}]
```