# Python to PHP - Base64 encode SHA256

Tags: php, python, sha256

Can anyone help me with converting the following Python script to PHP?

```
data = json.dumps({'text': 'Hello world'})

content_sha256 = base64.b64encode(SHA256.new(data).digest())
```

The value of content_sha256 should be

> oWVxV3hhr8+LfVEYkv57XxW2R1wdhLsrfu3REAzmS7k=

I have tried to use the base64_encode function, and will only get the desired result if I use the string:

```
$data_string = "{\"text\": \"Hello world\"}";
base64_encode(hash("sha256", $data_string, true));
```

but I want to get the desired result by using and array, not a quote-escaped string...

Comment: Have a look at [`hash`](http://php.net/hash) and [`base64_encode`](http://php.net/base64_encode).

Comment: @Gumbo, his problem isn't related to those functions - and he already has sample code written in PHP.

Comment: @MartinKonecny He added that three minutes after my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paul Crovella](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3942918/paul-crovella), you pointed out the correct direction. 
I have to do a string replace on the json encoded variable before I send it through the base64, to get the same string as the one made by Python:

```
$data_array = array("text" => "Hello world");
$data_string_json_encoded = json_encode($data_array);
$data_string_json_encoded_with_space_after_colon = str_replace(":", ": ", $data_string_json_encoded);

$data_string_base64 = base64_encode(hash("sha256", $data_string_json_encoded_with_space_after_colon , true));
```

Then I get the desired result, the same as in the Python script:
oWVxV3hhr8+LfVEYkv57XxW2R1wdhLsrfu3REAzmS7k=

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace python `json.dumps` with php `json_encode`

```
$data_string = json_encode(array('text' => 'Hello world'));
base64_encode(hash("sha256", $data_string, true));
```

Both of these functions take an associative array and transform it into a string representation. It is then the string that you do a hash/base64 encoding on.

Comment: I have tried that, but then I get the following string:
    
    atbx1Uf4ybQny9ENYejHvDHP9Wm7qNqyeagnBp92m2Y=

Comment: Yea, that seems to be a big issue :/. Can you work in Python to remove any of the spaces when doing `json.dumps`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311562/python-json-without-whitespaces